# ev hub motor spec, for pulling roller

Tags: electric-vehicles

I am working on a 500 kg roller, which I want to pull using electric motor. I am considering hub motor, since it is easier to frame a basic ev with it. Now I need to know the capacity of the hub motor, I need to choose.

Roller weight = 500 kg
Frame weight + driver weight = 150 kg
speed required = 10 km/hr
Surface on which the roller is to run is predominantly flat.

Things I need to know,
 1. Torque requirement for my problem.
 2. motor wattage 
 3. battery requirement, to run for 2 hours.

Being new to such design projects, I may have missed details. Please ask me for them. Help me with the calculation.

Comment: friction is unknown, so solution is unknown. Can you not compute the power to carry 650kg up a 1 deg incline at 10 kph? at what acceleration rate?

Comment: The closest coefficient of friction, I am able to find is;
0.04 - 0.08  car tire on solid sand, gravel loose worn, soil medium hard

I took this from;
Rolling Resistance
Rolling friction and rolling resistance
www.engineeringtoolbox.com

Fr = c * mass * acc. due to gravity
Fr=0.08 * 650 * 9.81
= 510.12 N

But we are already talking in terms of weight, so are we already done with our m.g calculation, so is my 650 kg already W, so Fr = 0.08 * 650 ?
If so, Fr = 52 N

The surface I am going to roll the roller on is a play ground with grass grown on a field level hardened soil.